# Salesforce Flow Get Record by Date Off by One

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

I'm working with the following very simple flow:

[image]

When I debug it the Get Stale Cases 'Get Records' element evaluates to the following:
[image]

This is the behavior that I would expect, however I just got a batch of emails for the set of test cases I created and modified on Monday 5/9/22:

[image]

List of Test Cases:
[image]

All test cases have the same created and modified date and similar times:
[image]

The Following formula is used to get the cases by date:
[image]
[image]

(Note: the day the flow ran was 5/11/2022. The day this question was posted)

Why would this be happening? I would expect the flow to send out the emails again if I ran it manually like above, however that behaves as 'expected'. Granted, I expect them to be consistent more than I expect them to be correct which is making this even more difficult to wade through.

Also, the flow is scheduled to fire at 6:00AM and I got the emails after 2PM. Is this something that can happen? This only ran on 10 records so scale is not an issue if that is even a problem in salesforce.